# Protestantism according to its tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

The Protestantism tag wiki says:

> Protestantism is technically used to describe churches and denominations arising from the Reformation, or descended from them, but also informally as a catchall for any Western non-Catholic church. Use this tag for questions relating to general beliefs and practices of such churches.

This seems deliberately intended to include restorationist denominations like the Mormons. [But the clear consensus is that Mormons aren't Protestant!](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/17518/6071)

I think this tag wiki needs to be edited. Any suggestions?

Edit: Another problem is that most protestants aren't "Western" now too.

Comment: I don't think that's the "catchall" being referred to there. I think that was trying to cover "non-denominational" groups that claim no affiliation but are actually Protestant. Restorationist sects are another matter.

Comment: @Caleb You may be right, but the tag wiki could still maybe be improved

Comment: With this suggestion comes the necessity for a [tag:restorationism] tag, no?

Comment: @fredsbend That could well be useful!

Comment: What are the eastern churches that adhere to the five solas?

Comment: @Juhani I don't understand your question.

Comment: Apparently I don't understand your edit. What do you mean by that "most Protestants aren't "Western" now too"?

Comment: @Juhani I mean that most protestants are in South America, Africa and east Asia.

Comment: Would you like to add that to your question, then? I thought you were saying that some traditionally Eastern churches are Protestant. I can imagine that somebody else might be confused as well.

Answer (score -2):

I proposed as an answer to [Is 'Non-Catholic Non-Orthodox Modern Western Denomination' an ok definition of Protestant?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39419/is-non-catholic-non-orthodox-modern-western-denomination-an-ok-definition-of-p) that Protestantism should be defined by the five solas. If you define it as a catchall term it doesn't really say anything.

I think we need a temporary "catchall" tag for rest of the "Western non-Protestant non-RCC non-Restorationist churches", until we can come up with something descriptive for them. Or no tag at all for them.

Comment: Typically, OP's label tag those [tag:jesus] and [tag:bible] and they often end up being closed as off-topic or primarily opinion based.